# Play default windows sounds using command prompt

Tags: windows, audio

I want to play default windows sounds (windows 10) in command prompt. I have used the command  rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep with success but it is unclear to me how I can play more windows sounds. Also it would be nice if there was the possibility to manipulate the duration, echo effect etc. Would that be possible? Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, what you are calling is a wrapper of the C++ function `BOOL MessageBeep(UINT uType);`, [described in MS documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebeep). I state 'theoreticelly', bcause then it should take parameters to select the system sound to play.

My experiments with doing so are inconclusive, and **I'd appreciate any input on what is happening**. For example, if a CMD prompt is opened and the following two commands are run, sometimes different system sounds are played... and sometimes *not*.

> rundll32 user32.dll, MessageBeep -MB_ICONEXCLAMATION
>
> rundll32 user32.dll, MessageBeep -MB_OK

Is the function not being called correctly, or is the 'package' broken or the wrapper damaged [hmm... seems like a question for UPS ;-)  ]?

*Caveat*: This is far from being an answer, but too complex to enter as a comment.